# Automation of google login apps with cypress

Tags: cypress

We are trying to automate an application(which has a google email for login) using cypress. But, it shows 403 error after login and not showing the app home page. It works fine when I click the same link manually. Does cypress work for google logins?

Tried cy.origin
Able to enter login details, but unable to see home page after clicking next.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.